# Random forests: weighting individual observations when resampling

Tags: python, r, scikit-learn, random-forest

I'm currently using a random forest on a nationally representative dataset with probability weights incorporated for each observation, with the hope that I can use these weights in the bootstrapping process.

I'm primarily an R user using the randomForest package, and after some investigation I've found that while you can weight particular classes, there doesn't seem to be a means to weight particular observations (see the comments of the first answer found [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/83104/weighting-more-recent-data-in-random-forest-model/91906#91906)).

Implementing scikit's random forest in python, on the other hand, has a sample_weight argument that looks to weight observations in the way I need.

I'm just curious to know: **is there a means to weight observations for random forests in R using existing R packages, or if I should move over to Python for this task?**

Comment: I don't see any indication that it can be done directly with `randomForest`.  You could do it yourself manually by creating a new data set that duplicates samples from the original one if you want to weight them.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I was thinking along those lines, but it could be problematic due to 1) The confusion matrix will then be for a  larger dataset rather than the actial sample size I need, and 2) This is nationally representative data, so doing such a thing would create a dataset in the hundreds of millions rather than a few thousand and making it quite difficult to get a quick answer given memory limitations